# Expected number of coin tosses before two consecutive tails using $T=\min \{n: n \text {th toss is a head }\}$

Tags: probability, markov-chains, expected-value

A fair coin is tossed until two tails occur successively. Find the expected number of the tosses required.

Hint : Let
$$
T=\min \{n: n \text {th toss is a head }\}
$$
find the distribution of $T$ and then condition on $T$.

---

The only thing I can get from the hint is that (i think) $T \sim \text{NB}(1,1/2)$. But I can't see what this has to do with finding the expected number of tosses until two tails appear consecutively. I don't really know what to do from here. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You have tagged this Markov-Chains, so the following Markov chain $Y_n$ is apt : consider three states called as $0,1,2$. When you're tossing coins, $Y_n$ takes the value $0$ if $X_n = T$. $Y_n$ takes the value $1$ if $X_n = H$ and $X_{n-1} = T$. $Y_n$ takes the value $2$ if $X_n = X_{n-1} = H$. Now, can you prove that $Y_n$ is a Markov chain on $\{0,1,2\}$ with some suitable transition probabilities? How can you reframe you question in the context of the Markov chain $Y_n$?

Comment: Let $p_n$ be the probability that no succesive tails appears upto $n$-th toss. Then we have the following recursive relation $$p_n = \frac {1} {2}\ p_{n-1} + \frac {1} {4}\ p_{n-2}.$$

Comment: Let $X$ be the random variable which counts the number of tosses required to get two succesive tails for the first time. Then $$P(X = n) = P(X \leq n) - P(X \leq n-1) = (1 - p_n) - (1 - p_{n-1}) = p_{n-1} - p_n.$$ Here you need to compute the sum $$\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} n\ P(X = n).$$ So for that you just need to find out what $p_n$ is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a smarter way to tackle this problem using conditional expectation. Here's this $:$

Let $E(X) = r.$ Then we have $$\begin{align*} r & = E(X\ |\ H_1) P(H_1) + E(X\ |\ T_1) P(T_1) \\ & = \frac {1} {2} (E(X) + 1) + \frac {1} {2} (E(X\ |\ T_1T_2) P(T_1T_2\ |\ T_1) + E(X\ |\ T_1H_2) P(T_1H_2\ |\ T_1)) \\ & = \frac {1} {2} (r + 1) + \frac {1} {2} \left (2\ \cdot \frac {1} {2} + \frac {1} {2} (E(X) + 2) \right ) \\ & = \frac {1} {2} (r + 1) + \frac {1} {2} \left (1 + \frac {1} {2} (r + 2) \right ) \end{align*}$$ Solving this equation you will get $r = 6.$

Comment: That makes sense to me! It's just that the question is asking us to use $T=\min \{n: n \text {th toss is a head }\}$, and I don't understand how to use $T$ to solve this problem.

Comment: @8622$:$ Note that $E(X\ |\ T \gt 2) = 2, E(X\ |\ T = 1) = E(X) + 1$ and $E(X\ |\ T = 2) = E(X) + 2.$ Now can you use conditional expectation to conclude?

Comment: Chattopadhyay I still can't seem to get it. With the assumption that $T \sim \text{Geo}(1/2)$ and using the law of total expectation I'm getting: $$E(X) = E(X|T=1)P(T=1) + E(X|T=2)P(T=2) + E(X|T>2)P(T>2)$$ and so $$ \mu = \frac{\mu+1}{4} + \frac{\mu+2}{8} + \frac{2 \cdot 5}{8}$$ which gives $$\mu = \frac{14}{5}$$ Where am i going wrong?

Comment: @8622$:$ $P(T = 1) = \frac {1} {2}$ and $P(T = 2) = \frac {1} {4}$ instead. Hence $P(T \gt 2) = 1 - \left (\frac {1} {2} + \frac {1} {4} \right ) = 1 - \frac {3} {4} = \frac {1} {4}.$

Comment: @8622$:$ If you toss a fair coin once then the probability of getting heads (or tails) is $\frac {1} {2}.$ Hence $P(T =1) = \frac {1} {2}.$ If you toss a fair coin twice then the only way to get heads in the second toss for the very first time is to get a tail in the first toss followed by a head in the second toss and the probability of that event is $\frac 1 4$ as there are only four equally likely events in the sample space namely $H_1H_2, H_1T_2,T_1H_2$ and $T_1T_2$ and out of these four events only one event suits your purpose namely $T_1H_2.$ So $P(T = 2)=\frac {1} {4}.$ Hope this helps!

Comment: Chattopadhyay Perfect, thanks so much for the help!